# Arduino too sensitive

Tags: arduino

```
int foot_sw = 12;
int c1 = 3;
int c2 = 4;
int c3 = 5;
int c4 = 6;
int r1 =  10;
int r2 = 9;
int r3 = 8;
int r4 = 7;
int timer = A0;
int timing = 1500 ;

void setup() {
digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
pinMode(foot_sw,INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(c1,OUTPUT);
pinMode(c2,OUTPUT);
pinMode(c3,OUTPUT);
pinMode(c4,OUTPUT);
pinMode(r1,INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(r2,INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(r3,INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(r4,INPUT_PULLUP);

}

void loop() {
digitalWrite(c1,0);
digitalWrite(c2,0);
digitalWrite(c3,0);
digitalWrite(c4,0);

while(digitalRead(foot_sw)==1){
timing = map((analogRead(timer)),0,1023,0,10000);
timing = timing;
}
digitalWrite(c4,1);

while(digitalRead(r4)==1){
}

digitalWrite(c1,1);

while(digitalRead(r1)==1){
}
digitalWrite(c2,1);

while(digitalRead(r2)==1){
}  
digitalWrite(c3,1);

while(digitalRead(r3)==1){
}
digitalWrite(c1,0);

delay(timing);
digitalWrite(c1,1);

while(digitalRead(r1)==1){
}
digitalWrite(c2,0);
digitalWrite(c4,0);
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(c1,0);
digitalWrite(c3,0);
delay(100);
}
```

This is to control 4 cylinders(c1,c2,c3,c4) in a particular order after initiating the sequence using a treadle switch(foot switch) but even before i press the switch the sequence starts automatically.

how to minimize this sensitivity of the board or is there any better way to receive a signal

THIS CODE WORKS WELL BUT THE INPUT PINS ARE A LITTLE SENSITIVE EVEN AFTER USING THE PULL UP RESISTORS CAN ANYONE SUGGEST TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM AND MAKE THIS CODE MORE EFFICIENT

IS THERE ANYTHING WRONG WITH THE CODE OR IS THIS A COMMON ISSUE FOR ARDUINOS?

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement some debouncing to your inputs.

Since things happens very quick in a microcontroller, sometimes a small noise will be detected by your code as a `1` state.

So to fix it, you read the pin multiple times (~10 times for example). If the pin value is `1` in all readings, you consider it as a true `1` instead of a noise.

Also you might add a capacitor between your pin and ground (10pF ceramic capacitor) to reduce noise.